# Parallel Software, Serial Hardware - Why?

Tags: cpu

For the past few years, I have noticed changes in approach to the design of Computer processors and other various components. For instance, while past processors focused more on the computing power of one core and the number of calculations per second, modern processors focus less on singular cores and put more emphasis on multi-threaded operation to increase efficiency. Many of the modern buses use serial connections, in opposed to parallel connections, to eliminate any timing gaps between signals and increase communication speeds.

However, with the wide-spread acceptance of these models in design, other methods have fallen by the wayside - ones that may have some merit to their use. With this, I present two questions:

1) Can a practical, massively-parallel CPU ever exist? In this case, the CPU is using all parallel buses for transfer of data that is more than one bit long, and can use light-based signal communications to pass data between components (particularly for PIC signals).

2) Can a parallel CPU power and operate more than one core simultaneously? Could cores and sub-cores be designed and treated like micro-controllers, running under one software (instead of each using its own software) with shared memory?

I picked up information for this idea from multiple sources, two being:

- http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/MPP-massively-parallel-processing
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking

I apologize in advance for sounding like a complete 'newb'. If I have incorrect information, please correct me. I am a bit new to this field. If you have any reading suggestions, please feel free to list them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a practical, massively-parallel CPU ever exist?

Ofc it can exist. If it is practical or economical is an entirely other question though. The problem with parallel lines is that they are often curved.

E.g. look at these two diagrams:

```
Simple straight though of 3 paralel lines. Works well

 S0 ------------------- S0
 S1 ------------------- S1
 S2 ------------------- S2
```

```
    ------------------- S0
    | |---------------- S1
    | | |-------------- S2
    | | |
   S0 S1 S2
```

The length of the path for the connection differs.

S0 to S0 has a length of 22.
S2 to S2 has a length of 16.

That means that a signal from S0 to S0 takes longer to arrive than a signal from S2 to S2.  This problem gets worse with wider busses. (more parallel paths).

This was less of an issue in the past were clock speeds were slower, but at GHz frequencies timing gets more critical. Just as an rough idea: speed of electricity though copper is about 280,000,000 m/s, quite close to `c`.

Light will move about 30 centimeter (roughly one foot) during a 1GHz clock cycles. That is 30cm in a straight path. CPU's contain anything but straight paths and we already run at multiples of GHz speeds.

> In this case, the CPU is using all parallel buses for transfer of data
>   that is more than one bit long, and can use light-based signal 
>   communications to pass data between components (particularly for PIC
>   signals).

Light based interfaces are not quite ready yet for production. There is a lot of research in it. There are working models in the lab, but it is not yet ready for mass production.

---

Second question:

> 2) Can a parallel CPU power and operate more than one core simultaneously?

Yes. No reason why it would not be able to (similar to current CPU's which run multiple cores in parallel). If we get more efficient communication then it becomes even easier to feed these core with data and thus easier to keep them loaded all the time.

---

> Could cores and sub-cores be designed and treated like micro-controllers,
>   running under one software (instead of each using its own software) with 
>   shared memory?

Yes, why not. Think mainframes (AS/400).  Or multi-CPU desktops. It is not usually done, but even a simple modern day desktop with multiple CPU is a setup where each CPU runs its own microcode, has its own memory controller and where you can pin your own programs to a specific CPU. You could take that a step further and even run a specific OS (which is what I assume you means with "softwares" on one specific CPU/core.

That would mean using an OS which is cooperates with any other OS, so either specifically written like that or something running in an type-1 hypervisor.

Comment: Can the parallel bus be 'turned on its side', to eliminate the width/sync problem? As the issue pertains to bus width and what happens when you put turns/corners in it, would it work to simply change the angle/position of the bus? Like ribbon cable?

Comment: Excellent write-up.  You can add that this also explains why hard drive interfaces switched from parallel to serial a few years ago.  As clock speeds increase, it becomes harder to keep parallel data bits "lined up" properly.

Comment: @TopHatProductions115 I am sure you could rearrange lines on a chip so that one bus is nicely paralel. There is more than one path on a chip though.

Comment: @Hennes Would it be impractical to arrange all parallel buses so that they stand perpendicular to the logic board? If it is feasible, I (with limited knowledge) would think it could lessen the issue of syncing the arrival of the bits at various components.

Comment: The challenge here is to have all the busses paralel. Doing that might work for a small subset, but no for dozens of interconnects in 3D space.